How to Convert Base64 string of tiff image to Base64 of PnG
I have a requirement to show tiff files in the UI. All browsers doesn't support tiff files so I'm planning to convert it to PNG file.
I don't have the tiff file, I'm getting the base 64 url of the tiff from another vendor Api.
I'm thinking to do the conversion in the server side and then pass the png base64 url to the client side and show in a iframe.

What have you tried so far?

FYI Base64 does one thing: Convert a bunch of bytes to a string presentation (and back). Period. There is nothing special with bitmaps or anything else

This function will take in the base64 tiff image and the stream you which to write the converted image to.
public void ConvertTiffToPng(string base64Tiff, Stream targetStream)
{
    byte[] tiffBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Tiff);

    using (MemoryStream msTiff = new MemoryStream(tiffBytes))
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(msTiff);
        bmp.Save(targetStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}

I would not recommend embedding the image in the html as a base64 encoded image. Instead set the source of the image to a controller that calls this function and writes the image to the output stream and add appropriate caching headers.
If you must have an base64 encoded image as the result:
using (var targetStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    ConvertTiffToPng(base64Tiff, targetStream);
    targetStream.Position = 0;
    string base64Png = Convert.ToBase64String(targetStream.ToArray());
}

